# 4-level ViewController navigation in iOS app using custom transitions

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I'm trying to build a menu with 4 different levels, where each level represents a `UIViewController`. I want the menu and each of its levels to be presented modally. Currently, I'm doing this by letting a base ViewController (VC) present another, which in turn presents a 3rd which presents a 4th (the structure would be A-B-C-D where each `-` represents a call to `UIViewController.present(_:animated:completion:)` for the respective level).

I'm then implementing the `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` and supplying it with a custom transition object. This works well for the first 3 levels (ie. the menu works as expected for level A-B-C), but when I'm on the 4th level and trying to dismiss it (ie. going from A-B-C-D to A-B-C ), the B level is briefly showing instead of the C level while the dismissal-animation is playing. After the animation is done, level C pops up over B again.

I suspect the problem lies in presenting more than 3 VC:s in a hierarchy somehow, but this does not occur when using the default dismissal animation instead of the custom one I'm using.

Maybe I should go for a different navigation approach, or is there some way to circumvent this behavior? I do need the menu to be "modal-style" which from what I can tell would prevent me from using a `UINavigationController` (I don't want the navigation bars).

Help is highly appreciated.

--- EDIT ---

Here is a "pseudo code" example of what I'm trying to accomplish, as the project is quite big and I'd have trouble pasting it all:

```
 class A: UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
   func viewDidLoad(){...}
    .
    .
    .
   @objc func presentB(){
     self.present(B, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomTransition(presenting: true)
   }
   func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return CustomTransition(presenting: false)
   }

 }


class B: UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
   func viewDidLoad(){...}
    .
    .
    .
   @objc func dismiss(){
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   @objc func presentC(){
     self.present(C, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   func animationController(forPresented:presenting:source:) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { ... }

   func animationController(forDismissed:) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {...}

}


class C: UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
   func viewDidLoad(){...}
    .
    .
    .
   @objc func dismiss(){
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   @objc func presentD(){
     self.present(D, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   func animationController(forPresented:presenting:source:) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { ... }

   func animationController(forDismissed:) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {...}

}

class D: UIViewController {
   func viewDidLoad(){...}
    .
    .
    .
   @objc func dismiss(){
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }   
}
```

Comment: please show us code for presentation, it looks like problem is there

Comment: Added some code but don't think that is it since it works when using the regular animation as well as for all levels but the 4th one.